# My Spring application cannot find my applicationContext.xml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classpath, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I have tried placing the xml file in everyplace it could be placed within my src folder but no matter where I put it it returns this error.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Below is the current structure of the folders in this project. I have placed the xml file everywhere I can within the src folder to no avail.

[image: Folder layout]

This is my first time using Spring, I'm pretty sure Im making a stupid mistake I just can't see it. Any help would be very well received thanks.

When I run the HelloSpringApp class it should run the application.

I'm running this in IntelliJ Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not picking it up because it's just not in the correct location.  Move that file into `/src/main/resources` and it should be able to find it.  Anything that's in `/src/main/resources` will be bundled in your jar and available on the classpath.